# Rewrite COM_CONTENT code to save data from form into database

Tags: form

I have rewritten **edit.php** in **/administrator/components/com_content/views/article/tmpl/edit.php** to create an Events tab just like in this screenshot

[image]

The only main issues I'm facing is how to to **Save** these 3 (Start Event, End Event and Location Event). I've looked up in **/administrator/components/com_content/models/article.php** and yet to find a good example to follow on how to save into the database.

Need help how to save these 3 new input into #__content table database. And Yes, I have created 3 column for these 3 in table #__content

Answer (score 1):

**No no no, do not modify core edit.php or add columns in a core table.** This file is going to be replaced in any upcoming update, and your new table columns are not a good practice.

- **You can create a view layout override** (but this does not solve the issue to save the fields): https://docs.joomla.org/Understanding_Output_Overrides#Copying_or_Creating_Layout_Files
- Better option, **Adding custom fields to the article component**: https://docs.joomla.org/Adding_custom_fields_to_the_article_component